# Trouble with DDR3 RAM

Tags: memory, bsod, ddr, memtest

I have a new custom built computer which is giving me some headaches due random crashes. Sometimes is just smaller problems, such as a Chrome tab closing. But there is times the whole system reboots, sometimes even without a BSOD. The computer specs

- Intel i5-4460
- Asus B85M-E
- 2x Kingston 4GB RAM DDR3 1600 MHz
- Zotac GeForce 480 GTX
- 1TB HD and a DVD drive
- 550W PSU

Things I've done so far:

1. Run memtest with both memories connected in dual channel. It returned several errors.
2. Run memtest in each memmory separatedly no errors. System seemed stable as well
3. Use the two memories in single channel mode. The system is more stable (i.e., usable), but I still get the eventual crash. I also runned Prime95 through a full day. From the 4 workers, 3 completed without errors, but one found an error after 22 hours running.

I have read suggestions to increase the memory voltage by 0.05V. However, my RAM is rated to 1.5V and that is also what it is set in the BIOS. I am a bit afraid of damaging it. Also, I guess it should not be needed, since most places I saw these recomendations where overclocking forums and I am not trying to overclock anything. I just need a stable system.

Since what seens to be the problem is the RAM, it might be usefull to know that my exact RAM model is the Kingston KVR16E11S8/4.

Comment: You need to solve your memory errors before you can solve your stability problems, which are likely connected, to the fact your getting Prime98 and Memtest errors.

Comment: Yes. I am working with the hypothesis that the root of my problemas are related to the memory errors. However, I exausted my ideas on how to solve them.

Comment: Possible root causes include: Memory module A, Memory module B, Motherboard hardware; memory interface. Likely cause for trouble; not ensuring ESD-safety.